# IBM DB2 trigger help needed

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_MODIFICATION_DATE (IN TBLNAME VARCHAR(30), IN ROWID INTEGER)
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE store VARCHAR(1000);
    SET store = 'UPDATE ' || TBLNAME || ' SET modification_date=CURRENT TIMESTAMP WHERE     id='||ROWID;
    PREPARE command FROM store;
    EXECUTE command;
END P1
```

It gets a name of a table, an id of a row, and update the modification_date column to the current timestamp.

I don't know how to write a trigger what calls this procedure every time after a successful update or insert of a table. (So what i want to accomplish is to store when a row was last touched).

Comment: There are plenty of trigger examples in the manuals. And I think updating `modification_date` in the trigger itself will perform much better than invoking dynamic SQL in a separate stored procedure.

Comment: Table names can be longer than 30 characters (I believe the "easy" limit on the iSeries is 32, but even there it can be longer).  To help avoid SQL Injection, you may want to verify against the sysinfo tables.  How does this interact with multiple schemas - does it default to the calling trigger's schema, the user's schema, the compiled procedure's schema?  Changing the table like @Charles suggests is probably the best long-term solution - would that work?  Otherwise, if you're defining a trigger, I'm with @mustaccio... (this is the reason for `before update`...)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define modification as a ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP?  Then db2 will update it automatically.

Comment: Certainly, I see this as the best long-term option, for a number of reasons.  Maybe he's not allowed to `ALTER` the tables, or his db doesn't support it (old version)?  +1, although perhaps you should also include a sample `ALTER TABLE` script.